# Clone 2 seperate harddrives onto 1 TB SSD (dual boot)

Tags: ssd, multi-boot, disk-cloning

I have a windows 10 machine and a xubuntu linux machine (both pc's are lenovo T450s) - i would like to put in a 1TB ssd in 1 T450s, and then clone each of the 2 drives onto that drive as dual boot ( so i can boot it up into windows or linux ).

Any hints if that is possible to do and how i can do that and what tools i might need ( never cloned anything before )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be a lot easier (and safer in terms of stability) to do a fresh install of Windows 10 and Xubuntu  and make it dual boot.

Then copy critical data across. Yeah you might have to re-install applications but personally I would do that.

If for some reason you cant and you need to clone the drives then you could:

- Download disk clone software such as [Macrium](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) or [HDClone](https://www.miray.de/download/hdclone.html) (both have free versions available).
- With HDClone you can boot out of the HDD to copy both
- Clone onto a 500GB partition on the new drive (leaving another 500GB partition for Xubuntu)
- Clone Xubuntu to the other 500GB partition.
- Do procedure for dual boot (you may find things online because there is thousands of articles on how to do it)

With HDClone when booting from a CD/USB when you get to putting the data on the new drive you can choose the partition to do it on. This is where you will choose either partition.

To create the partition, I would just plug it in to your existing Windows 10 machine and do it from there.

Comment: Problem is theres so many things installed on both for software development that it will take me forever to get to the same state so i need to get them cloned into 2 500 GB partitions.

Comment: How should the partitions be created on the large SSD ? will macrium guide me through that ? i would need a bootrecord somehow right for the dual boot - so its it 3 partitions or how ?

Comment: I would just put the 1TB HDD into the Windows 10 machine, partition it in there. Then boot into Macrium/HDClone and then you can select what partition to copy it onto.